# Java Singleton Access by Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, singleton

I'm working on a class where it is supposed to access an Singleton's class methods using reflection. Are there any best practices in here or pitfalls? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's the general "reflection is slow and should only be used as a last resort" best practice, but the guidelines that I follow, from simple to advanced:

- Cache any `Method` or `Field` or `Constructor` instances you get from reflection lookups. Looking them up repeatedly is *slow*.
- If you can, cache them globally in a `WeahHashMap` or similar that unloads them when the classes are unloaded so you don't leak class references from  your cache
- Even better, convert the `Method` objects to `MethodHandles` and then use `LambdaMetaFactory` to turn them into a `Function<Object[],Object>`, which will be almost as fast as a compiled method reference. *Still* cache the helper functions because creating them is expensive.